# Adding support for IE11 for a CSS3-based plugin

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, modernizr

I am using this plugin here:
http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/3DRestaurantMenu/

It works pretty well, however, it lacks support for IE11. In IE9 and lower, it appears as a 2D menu, disabling CSS3. However, IE11 apparently has partial CSS3 support, but incomplete support and hence it appears weird. The plugin uses Modernizr to recognize this, I believe. I have tried using the latest Modernizr version without success. Is there a way to add a header tag in there to detect any IE browser and disable CSS3 elements completely?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Looks good to me. In what way does it "look weird"? AFAIK IE11's CSS3 support is not "partial" or "incomplete".

Comment: The first page appears inverted and the last page is missing. I've checked it in IE11 in 2 different PCs.

Comment: Wow, that's weird. Let me take a look at it. I suspect it's not an IE11 problem, but rather an <=IE9 rule which is causing a funny interaction.

Comment: It works well in IE9 and lower, as it doesn't have CSS3 support and the plugin adjusts automatically as a 2D menu. The problem is specific to later versions of IE that I feel offers only partial CSS3 support. Possibly my IE11 is not updated and more support was added later on. Or as you say some interaction with rules applied for earlier IE versions. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to target IE11 using media queries:

https://philipnewcomer.net/2014/04/target-internet-explorer-10-11-css/

So it appears, IE11 is still missing complete CSS3 support, unless I'm missing something?